# Unknown behaviour due to memset function

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a memory eating binary.
So, I used malloc in while loop for allocating 1MB in one iteration.

I find some unkown behaviour, if I just allocate memory using malloc then the MemFree in /proc/meminfo is not decreasing as expected.

If I allocate the memory and do some memset then the MemFree in /proc/meminfo is decreasing properly.

Below is the code :

```
int main()
{
char *temp,*cmd="cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree";
    int i=0;

    while(1)
    {
    temp=malloc(1024*1024);
    //memset(temp,1,1024*1024);  //If not commented then MemFree is updated properly
    if(temp == NULL)
        printf("failed \n");
    else printf("allocated %d   %x MB\n",++i,(unsigned int)temp);
    temp=temp;
    system(cmd);
    usleep(1000*700);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: If you're on Linux and run [`sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting), you should see MemFree go down even without touching the allocated memory. Also have a look at Committed_AS which should go up regardless of the overcommit policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I guess your actual question is "why does it look like my program isn't using memory, unless I add code to write to it?" or something.

This is because the kernel is being lazy and hoping your application is over-allocating. Once you actually touch the memory, it has to do the work to make that memory available, and thus the measured actual memory use for that process changes then.

Comment: Thanks, what happens if I want to use the allocated memory some where in the while loop after may iterations , then the allocated memory will be available or not

Comment: @Ash As long as the allocation has succeeded, the system should be able to provide the requested memory. I don't think it's a 100% guarantee, that might be up to the kernel's policies, but you don't "need" to care. Of course, you'd have to save the pointers in the loop in order to use them later.

Answer (score 2):

Simply allocating memory will not mean the kernel will reserve that much physical memory for your program. Because of the practice of over allocating, which many many applications are regularly guilty of, the kernel just assumes that unless you are currently writing to or reading from that memory, you don't actually need it.

To make your program actually use that memory, have it write to it with random, garbage or even just set values.

Comment: Thanks can you provide any link which describes the above behaviour